# Probability of Quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How to determine an initial state of a two level system such that probability of the system being in that state does not change with time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compute the [Eigenstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_state) of the system. They represent stationary states and a system in this state will not change over time.